# Is it possible to map a parallelogram to a parallelogram using the (inverse) Joukowski map?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

Say you have a parallelogram in the complex Z plane, orientation and parameter $\lambda$ can be chosen size of sides has to be arbitrary. Can any such parallelogram be mapped to a parallelogram in the w plane(of any size/orientation) using the inverse Joukowksi map?

The Joukowski map is given by $J(z) = z + \lambda^2/z$ where $\lambda >0$
and $J^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\sqrt{z^2 - 4\lambda^2})$

So far I don't see how this could be possible but I may be mistaken. If it is indeed not possible how could I go about proving this? Any push in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: The map $J$ is analytic on its domain, so it preserves angles wherever $J'(z) \neq 0$, that is, at all $z \neq \pm \lambda$. Since there are only two such points, $J$ must preserve two of the angles of any given parallelogram in $\Bbb C - \{0\}$, and hence by symmetry preserves all four. NB this argument doesn't depend on the specific form of $J$, only on the number of solutions to $J'(z) = 0$.

Comment: @Travis Doesn't being conformal only mean angles are preserved locally? I tried mapping some parallelograms and graphing them and whilst the angles are preserved locally the sides are far from parallel(or even straight lines). For example [here](https://gyazo.com/20d56bb4346a2c2ae9bc6e948fcf6c6d) is a graph of a 5x5 square as well as the result of it's mapping. I set λ=1 for this example.

Comment: The only maps that preserve parallel lines and angles are linear maps $T(z)=a+bz$.

Comment: @dak.cola To be more precise, an analytic function $f$ preserves angles *at each point* (this is even weaker than what I would call "local"). On the other hand, any (real-)differentiable map mapping one parallelogram onto another must map corners to corners, and the above argument shows that $J$ preserve the angles at the corners. In particular, it cannot map a parallelogram to a parallelogram with different angle measures.